# Append select2 multiple in laravel vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Im having a trouble on how can I append data in select2, currently I can only manage to display the first item list of my cities based on the province selected. I've been using `onchange` to trigger the function. It would be great if anybody could figure out,  thanks in advance!.

[image]

```
data(){
   provinces: [],
   cities: [],
   brgys: []
}
mounted() {
    this.ini();
},
methods:{
     ini(){
         $('#kt_select_province').on('change', () => {
            let id  = $('#kt_select_province').val();
            id = id.map(i=>Number(i));
            this.provinces.map(i=> {
               if (id.indexOf(i.id) != -1) {
                  i.active="true";
               } else{
                  i.active="false";
                }
            });
            if(id.length != 0) {
               this.getCity(id);                //called city function             
            }
         });

      getCity(id) {
        axios.get(BASE_URL + "/api/city/" + id).then(response => {
            this.cities = response.data;                         // did not append here
            this.cities.map(i=>i.active="false")
        });
      },
     }
```

> cityController.php

```
public function show($id)
{
    return response()->json(City::whereIn('province_id', [$id])->get());
}
```